# What is RDSAppXPlugin?

Tags: terminal, eventviewer

In windows 2012 event viewer in the "Applications and Services > Microsoft > Windows > TerminalSerices - LocalSessionManager > Operational" path I can see the following event:
"Plugin RDSAppXPlugin has been successfully initialized"

Any idea what is that plugin? I could not find any source by googling!

Screenshot:
[RDSAppXPlugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rna58.png)